# Can @ControllerAdvise exclude or include some urls?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have some urls need to add `@ModelAttribute` from a `@PathVariable` like `/{city}/**`

I need to transform the city value to a bean, and use them in the view later;

Now I make it with `@ControllerAdvise` and add `@ModelAttribute` for all `@RequestMapping`

But some url dont contains a `{city}` path like `/`

And when request `/`, the Spring throw a Exception indicate that there's no `{city}` in the path

Can `@ControllerAdvise` exclude to advise some url like "/" or is there any other way without `@ControllerAdvise`  to implement it? I tried `HandlerInterceptor`, but it is not easily to solve it

EDIT:
As most of my urls like  `/{city}/**` , and in most `@RequestMapping` the `{city}` variable do not need to pass to service, I just transform it and pass it to the view. I dont will to see most of my `@RequestMapping` methods with a `City` parameter and just add it to the `Model` and also `@Controller`. It's very ugly.

So @Bhashit Parikh post may more meet my demands than @Ralph, I will test it later. Thank you all first!

Comment: You want some different handling for the `/` path, or do you just need to create a `null` bean instance whenever the `city` path-variable is not present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you are using a `@ModelAttribute` method like the following:

```
@ModelAttribute("cityBean")
public City city(@PathVariable String city) {
    return cityService.findByName(city);
}
```

What you can do is, update the above method as following:

```
@ModelAttribute("cityBean")
public City city(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Map<String, String> pathVars = (Map<String, String>)request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
    if(pathVars == null || !pathVars.contains("city")) {
        // The path variable not present, do whatever you need here.
        return null;
    }
    return cityService.findByName(city);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`Converter<String, City>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) to convert your City-String into a City-Object.

```
public class CityConverter implements Converter<String, City> {

    @Override
    public City convert(final String bidString) {
        return ....
    }
}
```

After you have registered this converter, at `FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean`

```
<bean id="applicationConversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converter">
        <set>
             <bean class="StingCityConverter" autowire="byType" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You can use it every where, for example:

```
@RequestMapping("city/")
@Controller
public class Controller {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/{cityId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView show(@PathVariable("cityId") City city) {
        ...
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView show() {           
        /* depends on what you want to do */
        return this.show(null);
   }
}
```

*I hope this answer your question, if not, please try to rephrase your question in order to point out your problem.*

Comment: Upvote from me for info about a feature unknown to me. However, will this really work? The [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert-Converter-API) here says that "For each call to convert(S), the source argument is guaranteed to be _NOT null_."

Comment: Bhashit Parikh: Yes it works (I use it for ID->DomainEntity for more than 2 years). (Of course you have to implement the converter logic) But I do not understand your problem with "not Null"? -- Then the converter is simply not invoked.

Comment: I meant that if the path-variable is missing, wouldn't Spring complain if the path-variable was missing (null). I will try it out though. Thanks.

Comment: If wont invoke that controller method, because it does not match, if this is the problem than use a second controller method without path variable